# Why do we have "EventMaskType" twice in the last line?

Tags: c, operating-system

I found following C-code in OS source code files. These 3 lines were in three different source files. Why do we have "EventMaskType" twice in the last line? It's giving me same output even if I remove first occurence of "EventMaskType" from the third line.

```
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;
typedef uint64_t        EventMaskType;
#define EVENT_MASK_OsEvent1  EventMaskType((EventMaskType)1u<<1)
```

Comment: `typedef unsigned long uint64_t;` should not be in an application header, but the compiler header. It is a C standard type, already defined in `stdint.h`. Every C compiler is required to provide it. That does not look like C code. If it is C++, please change the tag and text.

Comment: Actually it looks like bastardize C++ looking something like C. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is copied from stdint.h. I wanted to put all the related code here. And, it is C code.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;
typedef uint64_t        EventMaskType;
#define EVENT_MASK_OsEvent1  EventMaskType((EventMaskType)1u<<1)
```

The first line defines the type `unsigned long` to be also known under the name `uint64_t`. As pointed out in the comments this should be part of the standard header `stdint.h`.

The second line defines `EventMaskType` to be an alias of the type `uint64_t` (and as such transitively an alias of `unsigned long`).

The third line defines a symbol macro for the preprocessor, so that every (following) occurrence of the token `EVENT_MASK_OsEvent1` will be replaced by `EventMaskType((EventMaskType)1u<<1)`.

That in turn is the value `1u` (an `unsigned int`) which is cast using a "classic C style cast" to an value of type `EventMaskType` (which is an `unsigned long`, so instead of the cast one could also write `1ul`). This value is then shifted one bit to the left (result `2ul`) and finally cast using a *functional-style cast* to `EventMaskType` ...

```
EventMaskType( /* ... */)
```

... which doesn't change anything, because it's already of that type.